# How to check PCF version

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to know which `Pivotal Cloud Foundry` licensed version we are using? 
I see there are some marketplace services offered free in Public PCF but they are not available in the licensed PCF version we are using? I am assuming the version mismatch might be the reason.

Comment: You'd think it'd be easier to find the PCF version considering the PCF documentation is very detailed down to the version.

Answer (score 5):

As a normal `cf` user of Pivotal Cloud Foundry/Elastic Runtime/Application Service it can be a little tedious to figure out what version is running.

As a `cf` user you can start with `cf target` or `cf api` to get the target CF's API version:

`api version:    2.98.0`

Next, paginate thru https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-release/releases whilst searching for "2.98.0".

For 2.98.0 I found CAPI release 1.44.0 https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-release/releases/tag/1.44.0

Now, do a google search for "capi 1.44.0 site:https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf"

This returned one result - https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-0/pcf-release-notes/runtime-rn.html - So I now know my company is running PCF 2.0.

Next, to figure out which specific PAS version (or Elastic Runtime if using PCF 1.X).

Search thru the document for CAPI version "1.44.0".

This might return multiple versions. For API version 2.98.0/CAPI 1.44.0 I see that it might be any PCF/PAS version from 2.0.0 to 2.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

The public version will have almost all services enabled with various plans. The plans may include free tier.

The PCF setup for an organization purely based on the agreement with Pivotal. It will have only those services opted by your organization.

Please check with your Org Manager or administrator for PCF.

Answer (score 1):

When you mention "Public PCF" I assume you're referring to Pivotal Web Services (https://run.pivotal.io/)?  PWS is configured with access to a public marketplace with partner-supplied tiles / services. The private PCF that you're using is administered by your operations team, and it is basically up to them to decide what services to install / make available to you. You can find the list of available services for private PCF installations on the Pivotal Network site here: https://network.pivotal.io/

If you see the service that you need listed there, chances are that your operator will be able to install it onto your private PCF