# Detecting PCF version(s)

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

I have access to our corporate PCF, though both the Apps Manager webpage and the "cf" CLI (and thus the API).

How can I detect what version of PCF they're running?  There's nothing in the website that lists it, and the best I can find is using `cf api` which returns:

```
api version:    2.98.0
```

How can I map that to the PCF version, or is there another way to detect it?

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070765/how-to-check-pcf-version?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Apps Manager or the API (i.e. Cloud Controller) will report that information.  Both are just single parts of the entire system, so I think you could really only expect them to publish their own version information.

If you want to see versions of what is installed, you need to look at Ops Manager.  That will show you the tiles that are installed and each version.

If you don't have access to Ops Manager, you'd need to ask your platform operators.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer, but surprised that there isn't a table mapping these somewhere.  Seems rather odd that only admins and not devs have access to the underlying version #.  BTW, I did find out that we're using 2.0, so that API version (2.98) maps to PCF 2.0.

Comment: I don't know of a table that maps the PCF versions to the API version presented by Cloud Controller.  I suppose it could be done, if all you care about is the major/minor version.  You wouldn't be able to get the maintenance version of PCF that way, because the API version isn't going to change per maintenance release.  Also, to be technically correct PCF is just a bundle of software.  It doesn't really have a version.  Each tile installed by your Ops team has a version, so you have a version for Ops Manager and a version for Pivotal Application Service, which are totally independent.

Answer (score 1):

Usually via Ops Manager however another quick way is to click on the 'Docs' in Apps Manager it should take you to the documentation of relevant PCF version. For ex: https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-6/pas/intro.html means PCF 2.6

Please be advised that documentation link requires to be updated during upgrades so if someone doesn't do - it will be pointing out to older version..