# Cloud Foundry versions

Tags: cloud-foundry

Getting the accurate version of various parts of a Cloud Foundry installation is important ro refer to the right documentation pages, but seems a bit tricky.

Here is what I got so far:

- **CLI**: `cf -v`
- **Cloud Foundry API**: `cf api`
- **Buildpacks**: `cf buildpacks` lists the installed buildpacks, the version appears in the file name

Here is what I do not:

- **Cloud Foundry**, such as 2.4. According to [How to check PCF version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070765/how-to-check-pcf-version) there is a (painful) way from the API version, then the CAPI version, etc.
- **Service brokers**: `cf marketplace` lists available SB but no version info here, same for `cf marketplace -s postgresql`

For the desperate, the release notes such as https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/pcf-release-notes/runtime-rn.html can help.

How can I get the missing versions (preferably from command line or HTTP) as a regular user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pivotal Cloud Foundry, all of your version information can be found in Ops Manager. There is a handy diagnostic report you can export which gives you a JSON listing of all the versions of things you have installed.

It's under your user name in the upper right corner, then click settings and advanced.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/customizing/pcf-interface.html#settings

---

For PCF or CF, you can also get detailed version information from BOSH. Running `bosh deployments` will show you all of the BOSH releases that are part of your current deployment. Each BOSH release has a fixed set of software that it will install. If you care to go deeper, you can look at the individual BOSH release to get versions or more often git commit hashes for the software included in that release.

---

As an unprivileged user you can locate most of this information by running `cf curl /v2/info`.

Ex:

```
$ cf curl /v2/info
{
   "name": "Pivotal Application Service",
   "build": "2.4.2-build.33",
   "support": "https://support.pivotal.io",
   "version": 0,
   "description": "https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-3/pcf-release-notes/runtime-rn.html",
   "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.run.pcfone.io",
   "token_endpoint": "https://uaa.run.pcfone.io",
   "min_cli_version": "6.23.0",
   "min_recommended_cli_version": "6.23.0",
   "app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.run.pcfone.io:2222",
   "app_ssh_host_key_fingerprint": "62:b2:73:9c:c1:c7:4f:c9:79:0c:62:ec:a1:9a:f9:b0",
   "app_ssh_oauth_client": "ssh-proxy",
   "doppler_logging_endpoint": "wss://doppler.run.pcfone.io:443",
   "api_version": "2.125.0",
   "osbapi_version": "2.14",
   "routing_endpoint": "https://api.run.pcfone.io/routing"
}
```

- `build` gives you the PCF version.
- `api_version` gives you the Cloud Controller version
- `osbapi_version` gives you the open service broker API version (not version for individual brokers)

Obtaining the version for individual services is going to be the trickiest as it will depend on what information each service broker exposes. The output in the Marketplace is provided by an individual service broker, so if that broker were to include version information it would show up there. Similarly, there may be APIs & Dashboards exposed by individual service brokers that tell you more details like their version. You would need to consult with each individual broker to see how you can get more details about the version of it's that's been deployed.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting. Unfortunately both the Ops Manager and the bosh command line seem to be restricted to high privilege accounts. Added "as a regular user" to the original description.

Comment: I did a little digging and it seems like PCF, at least recent versions, exposes the PCF version as the build number through the `/v2/info` endpoint. I updated the answer with that info. Getting service broker versions is going to be really hard, as it's not exposed in any consistent way.